# Using JavaScript to swap between two unique DIVS using display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use JavaScript to swap between the visibility of two divs with an `onclick` on two buttons. It works, but with the code I am using if I click the button twice - it swaps again!

```js
function toggleOne(id,wid) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
        var f = document.getElementById(wid);
       if(e.style.display == 'block'){
          e.style.display = 'none';
    f.style.display = 'block';
    }
       else {
          e.style.display = 'block';
            f.style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
```

```css
.first {
 position: absolute;
 border: 3px solid;
 border-color: red;
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 left: 28px;
 top: 40px;
    display: block;
}
.second {
 position: absolute;
 border: 3px solid;
 border-color: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000000;
 left: 400px;
 top: 40px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleOne('first','second');">[button 1]</a> <a href="#" onclick="toggleOne('second','first');">[button 2]</a>
<div id="first" class="first"></div>
<div id="second" class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do you need to toggle one div with only one button? I mean click button 1 to display div1, click button 1 again to hide div2. click button 2 to display div2, click button 2 again to hide div2. Is that what you want?

Comment: There's no jQuery here. If you're not using jQuery, don't add the [tag:jquery] tag. If you *are* using jQuery, then **use jQuery**, and drop all the direct access to `document` and `.style`.

Comment: @AliSezişli I do want to use two buttons since the content in the divs will be two separate forms that the person could swap between optionally.

Comment: Those should be `<button>`s, not `<a>`s. You've even used the word "button" yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is written to *toggle* its inputs. It looks at the first element's current state, and *swaps* it, regardless of which button was pushed.

If you want to have one button always turn on one specific `div`, rewrite your function to always activate its first argument, and always deactivate its second argument, regardless of the state of each element:

```js
function toggleOne(onId, offId) {
    var turnOn = document.getElementById(onId);
    var turnOff = document.getElementById(offId);
    turnOn.style.display = 'block';
    turnOff.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.first {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 28px;
    top: 40px;
    display: block;
}
.second {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    left: 400px;
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleOne('first','second');">[button 1]</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggleOne('second','first');">[button 2]</a>
<div id="first" class="first"></div>
<div id="second" class="second"></div>
```